# Intersection product of $\mathbb{Q}$-Cartier divisors with irreducible complete curves is well-defined

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, intersection-theory, divisors

I am learning the notion of intersection product of a $\mathbb{Q}$-Cartier divisor with an irreducible complete curve on a normal variety. The definition I learned is that if $D$ is a $\mathbb{Q}$-Cartier divisor on a normal variety $X$ and $C$ is an irreducible complete curve on $X$, such that $lD$ is a Cartier divisor for some positive integer $l$, then we define $D.C$ to be $\frac{1}{l} (lD).C$.
I would like to show that this notion is well-defined.
What I have tried is to start with some local data $\{U_i,f_i\}$ for the Cartier divisor $lD$, and try to see why there is some factor $l$ coming from the intersection product $(lD).C$.
But I am stuck at the beginning. Could someone help me with this problem?Thank you so much in advance.

Comment: Why do you expect a factor $l$? Note that this intersection pairing takes values in $\mathbb{Q}$.

Comment: Thank you very much for your comments. I was thinking that the $l$ in the denominator for the definition of the intersection product needs to be cancelled by the intersection product $lD.C$ so that the resulting intersection product $D.C$ is well-defined.

Comment: No, it doesn't need to be canceled. What is indeed crucial is that torsion elements of $\mathrm{Pic}(X)$ all have zero intersection products with curves.

Comment: Thank you very much for your insightful comments.